# How to setup a sleuth span to enable reporting to Zipkin whenever it is closed

Tags: zipkin, opentracing

I am trying to create a tracer, then a span from the tracer.
Performing work.
Then closing the span.
I would expect that the close action will call spanReporter.report, which should post the data to an available Zipkin server (default localhost)

However, that is not happening.
Code below.
I noticed that I was using NeverSampler. Changed it to AlwaysSampler (for now).
I was also using NoOpSpanReporter as the default SpanReporter (which does nothing). I want to change it to a ZipkinSpanReporter. (Or something else).
This is where I am stuck.

Questions:

1. Based on the pasted code, what should be the correct type of default span report that I should use?
2. Which jar will have the correct Span Reporter. I see class ZipkingSpanReporter in spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin. So then, should I remove the spring-cloud-sleuth-* dependency and replace it with just the zipkin dependency?

---

```
public class TestClass {

    private TestClass() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    public static DefaultTracer createDefaultTracer() {
        boolean isTraceId128 = false;
        Sampler sampler = createDefaultTraceSampler();
        Random random = createDefaultRandomForSpanIds();
        SpanNamer spanNamer = createDefaultSpanNamer();
        SpanLogger spanLogger = createDefaultSpanLogger();
        SpanReporter spanReporter = createDefaultSpanReporter();
        TraceKeys traceKeys = new TraceKeys();

        return new DefaultTracer(sampler, random, spanNamer, spanLogger, spanReporter, isTraceId128, traceKeys);
    }

    public static Random createDefaultRandomForSpanIds() {
        return new Random();
    }

    public static Sampler createDefaultTraceSampler() {
        //return NeverSampler.INSTANCE;
        return new AlwaysSampler();
    }

    public static SpanNamer createDefaultSpanNamer() {
        return new DefaultSpanNamer();
    }

    public static SpanReporter createDefaultSpanReporter() {
        return new NoOpSpanReporter(); //What default span reporter should I use
    }

    public static SpanLogger createDefaultSpanLogger() {
        return new NoOpSpanLogger(); //I do not care about logging spans using slf4j for now
    }
}
```

Now the code snippet which uses the above:

```
DefaultTracer tracer = TestClass.createDefaultTracer();
Span mySpan=tracer.createSpan("testSpan");
 //Do work
tracer.close(mySpan);//This should stop the span and report the span to zipkin for display
```

**Note:**
This particular project does not have any http calls in any of its services. Its a data processing project.
@SpringBootApplication has not been used. (All zipkin examples use it though). Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Appears that a sleuth span is not the same as a Zipkin span.
Hence, in the above code there is no way to instantiate a default tracer with zipkin span reporter.
I converted the sleuth span into a zipkin span and then reported it to zipkin. The class to convert it is available in spring-cloud-sleuth-stream. I used pretty much the same class with some tweaks.